# Server not running body multipart/form-data

Tags: java, php, apache, server

I send on server multipart/form-data but not Error. No nothing! Simple 200 code request. I try to send multipart self.

I add header:

```
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
```

And send body:

```
--------b3a2fb0a4742753e0c507301a6bcb2bc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Test"

test
--------b3a2fb0a4742753e0c507301a6bcb2bc--
```

But PHP not showing $_POST variable Test

Java-code

```
void onWriteBody(String boundary, OutputStream outputStream) throws Exception {

            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

                // Reference for data
                Data data = this.data.get(i);

                // Start multi-part/data
                outputStream.write((boundary + "\r\n").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                // Add content-disposition
                outputStream.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(data.getName(), "UTF-8") + "\"").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                // If file then add tag for file
                if (data instanceof Data.File) {
                    outputStream.write(("; filename=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(((Data.File) data).getFileName(), "UTF-8") + "\"\r\n").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    outputStream.write(("Content-Type: " + ((Data.File) data).getContentType()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                }

                // Add new line
                outputStream.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes());

                // Write to output stream
                this.writeToOutputStream(outputStream, data);

                // End multi-part/data
                outputStream.write(("\r\n" + boundary + (i == this.data.size() - 1 ? "--" : "\r\n")).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            }

            // After end the operation close output stream
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

        }
```